# How can I navigate to the root page using GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I have looked it up, but how can I navigate to the root using the GoRouter package? Currently, I am using context.pop() corresponding to each current path, like this:

```dart
context.pop();
context.pop();
context.pop();
```

Here is how I have defined the GoRouter: [Please provide the GoRouter definition here.

```dart
class RouterService {
  final router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: 'rootPage',
        path: '/',
        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return MaterialPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: RootPage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Try `context.go('/');`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried that too, but I couldn't transition to the root.

Comment: That's strange. Does `context.goNamed('rootPage')` work? If not, your router configuration might be missing something. Do you have a `MaterialApp.router` with `routerConfig` set to your `router`?

Answer (score 2):

`GoRouter` provides a `canPop` method. From the documentation:

> Returns `true` if there is at least two or more route can be pop.

You can use it to pop your pages until there is 2 pages : the root, and the last page to pop.

```dart
void popUntilRoot() {
  while (goRouter.canPop()) {
    goRouter.pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I see, you use `while`. i will try.